# No acabar el hilo principal hasta que termine otra tarea lanzada segundo plano

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo un metodo con un completion que recoge un dato en segundo plano. ¿ Como hago para usar este dato en el hilo principal antes de que termine su ejecución ?

Es decir el hilo principal lanza un método en segundo plano y debe esperar a recoger un dato de este método antes de acabar.

Answer (score 2):

iOS no deja que el hilo principal permanezca parado más de unos segundos y aún así no es buena práctica en cuanto a usabilidad.

Te recomiendo que hagas las cosas en segundo plano las dos si necesitas parar el hilo o usa completions que comuniquen con el hilo principal cuando termine el proceso en segundo plano y este haga algo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Quizás algo así:

```
dispatch_queue_t mi_thread = dispatch_queue_create("mi_thread", NULL);
    dispatch_async(mi_thread, ^{

        //... recoge tu dato en segundo plano

        [self miMetodoConCompletion:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                //...usa el dato en el hilo principal

            });
        }];
    });
```

Comment: Buena idea, gracias